# Simulation -Discrete Time Hazard model

Tags: survival, discrete-time

How we can simulate the survival times for fitting discrete time hazard model?

Comment: I disagree with the VTC because "unclear": this is a general, albeit quite answerable, question about simulation for a very specific kind of data set.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you mean a discrete-time logit hazard, complementary log-log hazard, or probit hazard model, you can do this:

**1. Establish your model assumptions**

Specify a model incorporating at least two categories of assumption:

1. How does $h_{t}$, the discrete-time hazard function depend on *time*? For example:

   - Is $h_{t}$ *constant* across time? (I.e. independent of time.)
   - Is $h_{t}$ a *linear* function of time? (I.e. increases/decreases as a constant rate across time)
   - Is $h_{t}$ a *fully discrete* function of time (I.e. each period $t$ has it's own conditionally independent intercept term.)
   - Is $h_{t}$ some *more complex* function of time (E.g., does $h_{t}$ operate as a *quadratic function* of time? Does $h_{t}$ depend *linearly* on time, but with one or more discrete effects as specific time periods?)
2. Is $h_{t}$ conditioned on other variables besides time? For example:

   - Is $h_{t}$ *unconditioned* on non-time predictors? (I.e., is this a *baseline* model of $h_{t}$?)
   - Is $h_{t}$ *conditioned linearly* on any predictors?
   - Is $h_{t}$ *conditioned non-linearly* on any predictors? (E.g., two predictors plus their multiplicative interaction effect, etc.)

**2. Prepare for simulation (R sample code, assuming logit hazard, but stay tuned)**

1. Build some useful functions

   ```
   # create the logit function, and its inverse (over values of x 
   # from 0–1), the logistic function 
   logistic <- function(x) { return(1/(1+exp(-1*x))) }
   logit    <- function(x) { return(log(x/(1-x))) }
   ```
2. Specify $N$, the total number of individuals (units) at-risk at $T=0$

   ```
   N <- 1000   # You need to decide what N is, 1000 is just an example
   ```
3. Specify $T$, the maximum value of $t$ in your simulated study.

   ```
   T <- 20   # You need to decide what T is, 20 is just an example
   ```
4. Create a data frame called `Data` starting with the `ID` variable

   ```
   ID <- 1:N
   Data <- data.frame(ID)

   # Create conditioning variables (e.g., two dichotomous vars here, but
   # these could be whatever number and kind), and bind these to your 
   # data set
   var1 <- c(rep(0,(N/2)),rep(1,N/2))
   var2 <- c(rep(0,(N/4)),rep(1,(N/2)),rep(0,(N/4)))
   Data <- cbind(Data,var1,var2)
   ```
5. Format `Data` as a person-period structure

   ```
   expand <- function(x,t) {
     data <- x[rep(1:length(x[,1]), each = t), ]
     rownames(data) <- NULL
     return(data)
     }

    Data <- expand(Data, T)
    Data$period <- rep(1:T,N)
        for (t in 1:T) {
          varname <- paste("t",t,sep="")
          Data[,varname] <- as.integer(0 + Data$period == t)
      }
   ```
6. Prepare effect of time on discrete-time hazard function

   Based on your above model assumptions about how $h_{t}$ relates to time:

   i. Constant baseline hazard:

   ```
   # for a nominal hazard of 0.1:
   conslogit   <- logit(0.1)   # logit(.1)   = -2.1972246
   ```

   ii. Baseline hazard as a linear function of time

   ```
   # for a linear effect of time on hazard of 0.05 per 1-unit increase in t:
   linearlogit   <- logit(logistic(0) + 0.05)
   ```

   iii. Baseline hazard as a fully discrete function of time

   ```
   # for a fully discrete time effect on hazard (no. of discrete values
   # should equal T; here there are 20):
   discretehazards <- c(0.11, 0.12, 0.06, 0.20, 0.07, 0.17, 0.05, 0.04, 0.18, 0.06, 0.15, 0.09, 0.16, 0.25, 0.03, 0.15, 0.05, 0.11, 0.08, 0.14)
   discretelogit   <- logit(discretehazards)
   ```
7. Prepare effects of conditioning variables on $h_{t}$

   ```
   # for a nominal effect of var1 of 0.06 increase in hazard:
   var1logit   <- logit(logistic(0) + 0.06)
   #
   # for a nominal hazard effect of var2 of 0.04:
   var2logit   <- logit(logistic(0) + 0.04)
   ```

**3. Simulate your discrete-time survival data**

```
# Example for baseline fully discrete effect of time:
for (t in 1:T) {
  Data$hlogit[Data$period==t] <- logistic(discretelogit[t])
  }
```

```
# Example for conditional logit hazard model with constant effect of time:
# (The [Data$period==t] on the conditioning variables are probably only
# necessary if your conditioning variables are *time varying*: if the 
# values of var1 or var2 were to change over time *within individuals*.)
for (t in 1:T) {
  Data$hlogit[Data$period==t] <- logistic(conslogit + var1logit*Data$var1[Data$period==t] + var2logit*Data$var2[Data$period==t])
  }
```

etc.

`Data` now holds your simulated discrete-time data set!

**BONUS: 4. Wait a minute! I am using a discrete-time *probit* hazard (or complementary log-log) model!**

More or less exactly as above, ***except:***

1. For probit hazard

   ```
   # The inverse probit function (cumulative distribution function of z)
   invprobit <- function(x) { return(pnorm(x)) }
   probit    <- function(x) { return(qnorm(x)) }
   ```
2. For complementary log-log hazard

   ```
   # The inverse complementary log log function 
   invcloglog <- function(x) { return(1-(exp(-1*exp(x)))) }
   cloglog    <- function(x) { return(log(-1*log(1-x))) }
   ```
3. Where you have specified effects of time and/or conditioning variable effects using, for example, `var1logit <- logit(logistic(0) + 0.06)` instead use:

   - Probit: `var1probit <- probit(invprobit(0) + 0.06)`
   - Complementary log-log: `var1cloglog <- cloglog(invcloglog(0) + 0.06)`

   and then adjust the final simulation loop to use these variables as appropriate.

**PS: The code snippets are based on code from my own simulations. I selectively adapted to answer your question, but there *may* be errors in my answer, if there are, reach out to me and I will happily assist.**

Comment: where is the randomness aspect of this procedure? Given the value in `Data$logit` simulate a bernoulli variable with `rbinom`?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not too difficult.  To simulate one survival time:

1. Assume the unit is alive at the start of period/interval 1.
2. Let $h_1$ be the hazard rate for period 1.
3. Take a random draw $x$ from the uniform distribution on the unit interval.
4. If $x \leq h_1$, the unit died in that period/interval.  If not, the unit is alive at the start of the next period.
5. If still alive, repeat steps 2-4 the next period, and each subsequent period, until you either simulate a death or you reach some maximum period (after which you can only say that death occurs after that).  The max period will be limited by memory and processing time.

Repeat for each unit.  Depending on your specific case, you may want to repeat many times for the same unit, repeat across different units (which may have different hazard rates), or both.

Comment: Your simulation approach leaves out explicit assumptions about model conditioning, and the nature of the discrete-time hazard function's dependence on time.

Comment: @Alexis  That’s correct.  I left them implicit (the hazard rate depends on period and unit... somehow), because the OP provided no such details.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alexies for your valuable answer. but according your data code, each an every individual repeat 20 times. but in exact way of discrete time survival is repeat an individual until it reaches to its time interval, isn't it?l. as an example assume only 4 time period, then https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyFc1.png
If that so, how can we modify this code according to this?